# MySQL Query doesn't work with avg function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting some problem with an SQL query. I started doing a complex query, and when I found a problem I have tried to solve it with an easier query. The avg function doesn't work. I want to calculate an average of some votes (the rating attribute is a `SET Type` with the possible values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). But the avg function gives me a result of 6.2 that is impossible.

*Table*:

[image: Table]

*Query and result:*

[image: Query and result]

Answer (score 0):

Its actually alot simpler than you would think.

First Step:

Count all the rows you are getting the numbers from.

`$first = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME`

Second Step:

Add up all the rows you are querying with a `SUM`

`$second = SELECT SUM(rating) FROM TABLENAME`

Third Step:

Divide Second Step By First Step!

`$third = $second / $first;`

want to get fancier [Number Format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) it.

`number_format($third,2)`

Comment: How is that simpler than `AVG(rating)`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) for SET Type column:

> Functions such as SUM() or AVG() that expect a numeric argument cast
>   the argument to a number if necessary. For SET values, the cast
>   operation causes the numeric value to be used.

So you need to apply [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function to your query like this:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(rating AS CHAR)) FROM tsn_comments;
```